# Elasticsearch Complex Query, Mimicing Join Query

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, kibana, parent-child, subquery

So, let us say I have 2 indices users and products.

Within users I have the following format:

```
users:
{
uid:"00001",
name:"Hash",
country:"US"
},

Within the products I have the following format:

product:
{
productname: "Shoes",
.
.
.
uid:"0001"
}
```

My question is, how I can link these 2 indices and join its data together? like in MySQL I would do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN products p ON u.uid = p.uid;
```

I want the result to be the same as the above query, I mean like this :

```
{
name:"Hash",
country:"US",
productname: "Shoes",
.
.
.
uid:"0001"
}
```

Is there anything similar in Elasticsearch query? please help!

Comment: I'd recommend that you index the data in it's "joined" form, b/c ES isn't designed (read not fast) for SQL joins. If you need to preserve multiple key-value relationships in the "joined" version, [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) fields are the way.

Comment: @Nate found a better way, using ingest pipelines with enrichers, I am able to enrich ingested documents by data I want from another index, drawback is creating always a new version of that enrich index everytime you want to re-enrich existing documents... Figuring out a way to delete old enriched indices